# Edit/Import Comments to Fortify tool externally

Tags: xml, fortify, static-code-analysis

I have been tasked with adding comments from an excel file to the corresponding Fortify (static code analysis tool) FPR file. We use the Excel file to adjudicate each defect, then add the analysis level and any comments.  For this scan, I am required to actually use Fortify's comment feature.  There are over 7000 defects, so, as you can imagine, doing this manually would be monumentally tedious and time consuming.  I am looking for a method to automate this... if possible.

I began by opening the FPR (glorified zip file), and exploring how data is saved.  I can't say that I know, but I did discover that Comments seemed to be saved or imported using the file `audit.xml`.  I manually added a comment with the formatting (XML tags) my test comments seemed to be recorded.  It was a success.  The test comment I added manually into the xml file did show up in the Fortify Audit Workbench in reference to the correct defect.

So created an XML generating program using VBA to parse the info from each defect, and created a new entry in `audit.xml` for each.  This method was not a success.  None of my new comments are showing up in Fortify. So I'm back to square one.

Does anyone know of a method to accomplish my task?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the prefer method to your scenario is using Software Security Center (SSC), wich is included in Fortify installation. You can also export the issues from SSC to your preferred bug tracker as a additional step. Maybe this helps.